# Reduction grammar

Tags: adjective-phrases, reduced-relative-clauses

Is the below an adjective phrase?

> "to keep something warm, causing it to develop, esp. to keep eggs warm
>   until the young are born:"

Comment: It's not a complete sentence.  It sounds like a definition of some term, probably **incubate**.

Comment: thanks.w hat about this one  "It can fragment habitats in a variety of ways, reducing the number of pollinators, which in turn may reduce the number or size of the flowers"

Comment: What about it?  It's a complete sentence.  I'm not sure what question you want answered.

Answer (score 1):

When you look up a verb in a dictionary, it probably would give you such explainations:

incubate

> To keep something warm, causing it to develop, esp. to keep eggs warm
>   until the young are born:

It always begins with "To do sth". It's a reduction of

> It means to keep something warm ...

or

> "Incubate" means to keep something warm ...

Comment: thank you so much for your exhaustive explanation